# AG Grid: Save ColumnState in ColumnDefs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I want my ColumnState to persist when the user reloads the site. For that reason, I am saving the colstate in the localStorage:

```
const currentColState = gridRef.current.columnApi?.getColumnState();
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(currentColState))
```

On Reload I am setting columnDefs, and a useEffect that triggers when columnDefs is changed does the following:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("key")){
    const storageState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key");
    gridRef.current.columnApi?.applyColumnState({state: storageState, applyOrder: true});
}
```

I have a button, which enables/disables floating filters. When clicked this happens:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (gridRef.current?.api) {
        gridRef.current.api.setDefaultColDef({ ...defaultColDef, floatingFilter: floatingFilters });
        }
    }, [floatingFilters]);
```

This will negate my columnState.

How can I save the columnState into columnDefs to use these in the floatingFilter use Effect?
If you have other ideas to do this, i am open for that.

I had the Idea of using the API in the html part:

```
<AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
    columnDefs={HERE}
    ...
/>
```

But I dont know how I would do that. Solutions that target this way are also welcome :D

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code and explain a bit more precisely what you want to do? I am working with AG grid in react and saving and applying column state works every time. Did you check if your grid API is defined when you try to apply? Also, check for onGridReady method. It is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not see any problems with the codes you shared.

Normally, setting floating filters should not interfere with the applied column state.

Please try the following

1. Try to restore them using onFirstDataRendered event

```
const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params) => {
  restoreState()
}, [restoreState]);

const restoreState = useCallback(() => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('colState')) {
    console.log('no columns state to restore by, you must save state first');
    return;
  }

  var currentColState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('colState'));

  gridRef.current.columnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: currentColState,
    applyOrder: true,
  });
  console.log('column state restored');
}, []);
```

2. Do not forget to pass defaultColDef on your AgGridReact component

```
<AgGridReact
  ref={gridRef}
  rowData={rowData}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
/>
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/ld87cd2ml34EsyhT

Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/ld87cd2ml34EsyhT?preview

**To reproduce**

Click on the Country column to sort in ascending order and then click on the Save State button. Click on the Toggle Floating Filters button and refresh the page. The grid should be sorted in ascending order according to the Country column.